# Angular ui-grid export to csv with infinite scroll but need to export all data

Tags: angularjs, csv, grid

I have angular's ui-grid implemented along with infinite scroll enabled. Currently it only fetches 100 rows at a time - when I enable export to csv in the grid options, by default it will export only how many rows are visible. My question, is there a way to export but get all rows of data? Any input/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: i know there is an option to export "all data" and export "visible" but within the export all data - do I need to make a call to retrieve the full data list?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue back in months and I found this solution :

From the [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions), you can use `exporterAllDataFn` property in `$scope.gridOptions`

```
gridOptions.exporterAllDataFn = function () {
  return $http.get('/data/100.json')
}
```

As far as I unsterstood, this function is called once you clicked on the `exporterMenuCsv` menu button 'Export all data as csv'

I also found this good [tutorial](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/misc/tutorial/405_exporting_all_data_complex.ngdoc) made by PaulL1, major contributor of the ui-grid lib.

Note: I quickly ended up not using this solution: I wanted to add some formatting/filtering/sorting on each columns, so I made my own export function.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have filtering and sorting built in also, do you mind sharing an example of the export function you added? Basically on my dto i have a parameter: isPaged: true - that is calling a different repository method to run paging and only return 100 at a time - so in my new function I'll need to pass the grid dto with isPaged: false so it calls the getAll method which will return the full result set on export

Comment: Sharing my code won't be usefull I guess. But here is what I did :
 - Created a service 'dataExportServices' In which you can find a function where you make your call to retrieve all data and your filtering/sorting/formatting functions.
 - I created a graphical component that call this export function in the service.